# UDP Echo client/server in C#/C++ not returning message

Tags: c#, c++, network-programming, udp

I have a server written in C++ and a client written in C#. The client sends its packet to the server, the server receives it, then sends it back. Unfortunately, everything works EXCEPT when the server sends the message back. Here is the simple code:

// SERVER

```
    if ((recv_len = recvfrom(s, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_sender, &si_senderSize)) == -1)
    {
        die("recvfrom()", s);
    }

    //print details of the client/peer and the data received
    printf("Received packet from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(si_sender.sin_addr), ntohs(si_sender.sin_port));

    std::cout << "Data: " << buf << std::endl;

    //now reply the client with the same data information

    if (sendto(s, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &si_sender, si_senderSize) == -1)
    {
        die("sendto()", s);
    }

 //cleanup here
```

//CLIENT

```
    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool found = false;
        byte[] text_to_send = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("networkinfo");
        client.Send(text_to_send, text_to_send.Length);

        IPEndPoint serverResponse = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

        while (!found)
        {
            if (client.Available > 0)
            {
                byte[] responseBuffer = client.Receive(ref serverResponse);
                string response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseBuffer);
                writeIPAddress(serverResponse.Address.ToString(), serverResponse.Port.ToString());
                found = true;
            }
        }
```

The server does not fail on the sendto() function, but the while loop in the client polls forever because it is not detecting information to receive on the network, but the sendto() function didn't return error?

Any ideas to where the network data is??

Comment: First ovservation: you should never use .Available like that. The only (off the top of my head) valid use of .Available in a branch is to decide between sync vs async. Second observation: does either party ever close their send socket? If not: how do you expect this conversation to end?

Comment: MSDN: "The Available property is used to determine the amount of data queued in the network buffer for reading. If data is available, call Read to get the data. If no data is available, the Available property returns 0." I thought I would use that so i don't get stuck in the Receive blocking call? (of course I would take out while() for that) Also, server will never close its socket.

Comment: @d "available" is not the same as "incoming". It just tells you what is already at the NIC. Other than "sync vs async" that is virtually meaningless. Let's put it this way: I do a lot of network io code. The one thing I never look at? .Available

Comment: @MarcGravell Oh ok I see what you are saying. I will take out .Available. I will try a similar function to the Select() function in C and see how that works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i figured it out finally and I want to post the resolution to the problem so other people won't have this headache.

The problem was broadcasting a UDP packet with UDPClient. You CANNOT receive with the same UDPClient object after you broadcast a packet (using ipaddress.broadcast or "255.255.255.255").  The solution I ran into was to immediately close this object, open another one on the same port, then use that new object to receive the response.

```
//setup broadcast client
broadcastClient = new UdpClient(5454);
broadcastAddress = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 8888);
broadcastClient.Connect(broadcastAddress);

//send and immediately close
byte[] text_to_send = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("networkinfo");
broadcastClient.Send(text_to_send, text_to_send.Length);
broadcastClient.Close();

//open up new client to receive
UdpClient receivingClient = new UdpClient(5454);
IPEndPoint serverResponse = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
byte[] message = receivingClient.Receive(ref serverResponse);
string messageReceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(message);

Debug.WriteLine(messageReceived);
```

I did not see anything about this quirk (problem?) on MSDN, so I'm not sure if this is a bug or it is as intended and just not documented.